# How to have Sidebar Overlap Images

Tags: html, css

I've used this tutorial http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/30/google-nexus-website-menu/ to create a Sidebar in my _Layout code. I'm trying to have the sidebar overlap anything in RenderBody(). When the sidebar is open on the mobile, it appear behind the images.

Image depicting issue: http://snag.gy/uN9GF.jpg

My Body example code can be found here
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxLvEQ

_Layout.cshtml code

```
<div class="container">
    <ul id="gn-menu" class="gn-menu-main">
        <li class="gn-trigger">
            <a class="gn-icon gn-icon-menu"><span>Menu</span></a>
            <nav class="gn-menu-wrapper">
                <div class="gn-scroller">
                    <ul class="gn-menu">
                        <li class="gn-search-item">
                            <input placeholder="Search" type="search" class="gn-search">
                            <a class="gn-icon gn-icon-search"><span>Search</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="gn-icon gn-icon-download">Popular</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-cog">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-help">About us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /gn-scroller -->
            </nav>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops">Test Sidebar</a></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>

     @RenderBody()
</div><!-- /container -->
<script src="../../Scripts/classie.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/gnmenu.js"></script>
<script>
    new gnMenu(document.getElementById('gn-menu'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to fix your problem:

1. Set `z-index: 1;` on `gn-menu-main`. Normally, I'd also tell you to set its `position` to something other than `static`, or else the `z-index` will have no effect. Looking at the [site you linked](http://testingwebground.azurewebsites.net), though, it appears you already have it set to `fixed`, which is fine.
2. Wrap `@RenderBody()` in a container div and set `position: relative;` on it. The relative positioning ensures that none of the container div's child elements can overlap its sibling elements unless the div itself does-- and we know it won't since its only sibling (`gn-menu-main`) has `z-index: 1;`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. It's greatly appreciated. Fixed my problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust the z-index of "gn-menu-wrapper" class.

for example:-

.gn-menu-wrapper{z-index:1}

if this is not working add more value to z-index.

.gn-menu-wrapper{z-index:99999}

Comment: Just tried this method, overlaps on desktop, doesn't on mobile.

Comment: Can you please give me the link of your website, then only its possible to understand your problem.

Comment: Sure thing, I pushed to an azure server here. http://testingwebground.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 0):

I have solved your problem.

You just have to add "**z-index:1**" in

**COMPONENT.CSS**

**line number** - 96

**class** - .gn-menu-wrapper

**add** - z-index:1

This is working see the screen shot

[image]

Comment: Hi Ajay, which browser are you testing it on, I tried on chrome and it still exhibits the issue.

Comment: I tried mobile chrome and firefox, issue still remains. I've also published that fix you suggested to the link if you want to try on mobile

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul id="gn-menu" class="gn-menu-main">
        <li class="gn-trigger">
            <a class="gn-icon gn-icon-menu"><span>Menu</span></a>
            <nav class="gn-menu-wrapper">
                <div class="gn-scroller">
                    <ul class="gn-menu">
                        <li class="gn-search-item">
                            <input placeholder="Search" type="search" class="gn-search">
                            <a class="gn-icon gn-icon-search"><span>Search</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="gn-icon gn-icon-download">Popular</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-cog">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-help">About us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /gn-scroller -->
            </nav>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops">Test Sidebar</a></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>

     @RenderBody()
</div><!-- /container -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/GoogleNexusWebsiteMenu/css/normalize.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/GoogleNexusWebsiteMenu/css/demo.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/GoogleNexusWebsiteMenu/css/component.css" />
<script src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/GoogleNexusWebsiteMenu/js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/GoogleNexusWebsiteMenu/js/gnmenu.js"></script>
<script>
    new gnMenu(document.getElementById('gn-menu'));
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, there's no explanation. There's only css added.